# web.config is being used by another process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, web-config, visual-studio-2015

I'm unable to change my web.config file from Visual Studio, both 2012 and 2015

Once I try it open the 'Save As' dialog box.

Also changing it with external editor doesn't work.

Using ProcessExplorer, I've Identified that it is being locked by **Microsoft.visual studio.web.host.exe** however I couldn't find a way to disable this service or maker it release the web.config file.

Comment: Have you tried the tool Unlocker? Or the x64 bit one?

Comment: This is a work-around, not a solution.

Comment: *There is a bug with vs2010, almost every time I compile a particular solution in vs2010 I get the same error and have to rename the exe:(* See if you can get a repro and show us and log a Connect case... Also in procExplorer is the web host the only process locking it, there's no hierarchy?

Comment: Was this solved on a later versions? is there a way to disable the web.host executable?

Comment: Yeah it was fixed in 2012.. how did you go with a [mcve]

Comment: If I could get such example, I could probably reduce and solve it. hence the entire problem. however on all VS the Microsoft.visual studio.web.host.exe is running. so I'm trying to reduce the problem into just disable it.

Comment: I'm having same issue with VS 2015 Professional on 64 bit Windows 10